# How can I put the code block into a function in c#?

Tags: c#

I would want to use a function in the place of the `if/else`-clause.

```
public void CopyPasteFiles(string modelInfoFilePath, string definitionFilePath, string pedName)
        {
            string messageBoxText = "Looks like a ped with this name already Exists. Please try a new Name.";

            if (this.IsMale)
            {
                modelInfoFilePath = Tokenizer.Detokenize(modelInfoFilePath);
                this.NewModelInfoPath = modelInfoFilePath.Replace("Z_Z_ProxyPed_MR1_000_Dummy", pedName);

                if (!File.Exists(this.NewModelInfoPath))
                {
                    File.Copy(modelInfoFilePath, this.NewModelInfoPath, false);
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(this.NewModelInfoPath);
                    fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    RsMessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
                }

                definitionFilePath = Tokenizer.Detokenize(definitionFilePath);
                this.NewDefinitionPath = definitionFilePath.Replace("Z_Z_ProxyPed_MR1_000_Dummy", pedName);

                if (!File.Exists(this.NewDefinitionPath))
                {
                    File.Copy(definitionFilePath, this.NewDefinitionPath, false);
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(this.NewDefinitionPath);
                    fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    RsMessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
                }
            }
            else if (this.IsFemale)
            {
                modelInfoFilePath = Tokenizer.Detokenize(modelInfoFilePath);
                this.NewModelInfoPath = modelInfoFilePath.Replace("Z_Z_ProxyPed_FR1_000_Dummy", pedName);
                if (!File.Exists(this.NewModelInfoPath))
                {
                    File.Copy(modelInfoFilePath, this.NewModelInfoPath, false);
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(this.NewModelInfoPath);
                    fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    RsMessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
                }

                definitionFilePath = Tokenizer.Detokenize(definitionFilePath);
                this.NewDefinitionPath = definitionFilePath.Replace("Z_Z_ProxyPed_FR1_000_Dummy", pedName);
                if (!File.Exists(this.NewDefinitionPath))
                {
                    File.Copy(definitionFilePath, this.NewDefinitionPath, false);
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(this.NewDefinitionPath);
                    fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    RsMessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have lots of `if`s and `else`s! Which one in particular are you talking about and have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: This might help you start refactoring : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#:~:text=Source%20code%20refactoring%20can%20improve,base%20from%20within%20your%20editor.

Comment: You have correctly used `if(male)...else if(female)`. I'm just missing the `else` part(Nonbinary) ;-)

Comment: Start by naming the functon. Then it will be a lot easier. If you can't find a good name you can't refactor the code..

Comment: What's your IDE ? As @Helio said, refactoring tools are a great way to automate code split. With VS (not VS CODE), you can select a portion of code and trigger the "extract function" refactor tool. That said, you should consider isolating repeating code as soon as possible. It's often easier to properly structure the code earlier in the dev process.

Comment: the only place that differs in the if and else blocks is the string infix: `MR1`. so basically you need to change that string in the blocks and execute the rest afterwards. this will remove half of the code

Answer (score 0):

Let's see: you have the following piece of code which comes back constantly:

```
if (!File.Exists(New_Information))
{
    File.Copy(Existing_Information, New_Information, false);
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(New_Information);
    fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
}
else
{
    RsMessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
}
```

This means that you need to write a function, using the two parameters `Existing_Information` and `New_Information`, something like:

```
void Do_Something(var Existing_Information, var New_Information)
{
    if (!File.Exists(New_Information))
    {
        File.Copy(Existing_Information, New_Information, false);
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(New_Information);
        fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
    }
    else
    {
        RsMessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
    }
}
```

Inside your code, you just replace your `if`-loop by that function, using the correct parameters:

```
Do_Something(modelInfoFilePath, this.NewmodelInfoFilePath);
...
Do_Something(definitionFilePath, this.DefinitionFilePath);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should analyze what parts of your code are the same, and which variables can be substituted for parameters.

Looking at your code, I see 4 parts that are somewhat similar.

2 of them are for `this.IsMale`, and two of them are `this.IsFemale` (which could also be `!this.IsMale` considering a binary biological standpoint). We can use this to change the string itself, instead of using two `if` statements.

2 of them use `modelInfoFilePath`, while the other 2 use `definitionFilePath`.
If we declare these first, we can use them as parameters for a `CopyFile` method.

Take a look at this code below, you might see what I mean.

```
public void CopyPasteFiles(string modelInfoFilePath, string definitionFilePath, string pedName)
{
    modelInfoFilePath = Tokenizer.Detokenize(modelInfoFilePath);
    definitionFilePath = Tokenizer.Detokenize(definitionFilePath);

    string pedReplaceName = this.IsMale : "Z_Z_ProxyPed_MR1_000_Dummy" ? "Z_Z_ProxyPed_FR1_000_Dummy";

    // replace names
    this.NewModelInfoPath = 
    modelInfoFilePath.Replace(pedReplaceName, pedName);
    this.NewDefinitionPath = 
    definitionFilePath.Replace(pedReplaceName, pedName);

    // copy files
    CopyFile(modelInfoFilePath, this.NewModelInfoPath);
    CopyFile(definitionFilePath, this.NewDefinitionPath);
}

public void CopyFile(filePath, newFilePath) {
    if (!File.Exists(newFilePath))
    {
        File.Copy(filePath, newFilePath, false);
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(newFilePath);
        fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
    }
    else {
        RsMessageBox.Show("Looks like a ped with this name already exists. Please try a new Name.");
    }
}
```

Comment: .IsMale is a  bool and is connected with a wpf radiobutton